# react update component props outside of component class

Tags: reactjs

I have some problem with creating React app. Here is the problem:

```js
import React from 'react';

const VIEW_MAIN = 0;
const VIEW_SUB = 1;

const VIEWS = {};
VIEWS[VIEW_MAIN] = (<ViewMain someProps={...} />);
VIEWS[VIEW_SUB] = (<ViewSub someProps={...} />);

const AppContent = React.createClass({
    render() {

        let renderDOM = null;

        if(this.props.view === VIEW_MAIN) {
            renderDOM = VIEWS[VIEW_MAIN];
        }
        else {
            renderDOM = VIEWS[VIEW_SUB];
        }

        return (
            <div id="ViewContainer">
                {renderDOM}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

You can see that "VIEWS" constant variable contains 2 views, VIEW_MAIN and VIEW_SUB. Each view is React Component.

Both components have same property named "someProps". Now, this is the problem. I want to add property of "AppContent" component into both two React Components, but of course, it is impossible because they are outside of class definition.

So move them into the class definition, problem is I don't know where should I put. Should I put inside of "render" method? I think that is bad idea, because render method will execute many times.

If I use "class" keyword instead of using createClass, I think it is possible if the defining "VIEWS" constant variable codes are inside of constructor function(constructor()) but i don't like to use them.

I typed code like this temporarily:

```js
const AppContent = React.createClass({
    _initViews() {
        if(typeof this.VIEWS === 'undefined') {
            this.VIEWS = {};
            this.VIEWS[VIEW_MAIN] = (<ViewMain someProps={this.props.some} />);
            this.VIEWS[VIEW_SUB] = (<ViewSub someProps={this.props.some} />);
    },
    render() {
        this._initViews();

        ...
    }
});
```

I added `_initialViews` method inside of class, and execute it when render calls. It works fine, but the problem is always executing "_initViews" method on rendering `AppContent` component. I want to execute only once, and I think using react like that is bad idea.

Should I just use Class keyword instead? As i heard, there is "setProps" method inside of React but that is now deprecated, and i also think that using setProps method is bad idea.

Is there a way to good practice or better solution what am I trying? If it is, it will be very appreciate it advice me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement [stateless functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions). Fill `VIEWS` with those functions and call it in your app replacing `{renderDOM}` by something like `<renderDOM someProps={this.props.some}/>`

To avoid having a component render multiple times, use `shouldComponentUpdate`. Otherwise, even if a component is re-rendered multiple times, if the generated virtual DOM is consistent with the browser DOM, there will be no refresh on the page for those component.

Answer (score 2):

ReactJS is all about rendering the state of your application. When state has changed, you render again the whole application. The trick is ReactJS do it fast, thanks to Virtual Dom.

Answering your question: it is fine to render component many times.

Take a look to introduction videos: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/videos.html

And Thinking in React section: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html